# How to match arbitrary data using hash codes?

Tags: c#, python, .net, sorting, hash

I have some points in space where each point has an `id`. I also have a subset of these points in another group that have different `id` values.

How can I create a new type of `id` for both groups of points so that the points that have the same coordinates end up using the same `id` values?

I assume I need to generate hash codes using their coordinates which should give me the same `id` value for points that have the same coordinates, right?

I am confused how I could use it because the set of hashcodes is much smaller than float[3]. So not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: Which language are you using?  C# or Python?

Comment: Actually I didn't start writing the program, so could be either. The program I will use this code supports both.

Comment: I ask because it's preferred for SO questions to have at most one language tag.  Questions which are too open-ended are at risk of being closed, which won't help you get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I added python because if it has some fancy library that would help, then I would use that language. Otherwise would be C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you mean here, but you *could* use [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) with a `tuple`:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x,self.y,self.z))

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return (self.x,self.y,self.z) == (other.x,other.y,other.z)
```

Now, objects which contain the same point all hash to the same value.  As a side benefit, they can now be used as dictionary keys or in set objects a little bit more reasonably.

---

Of course, if you're going to write a class this simple, you might want to consider a [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead.  You could even subclass it (it's all spelled out in the link).  This has the advantage of the object being immutable -- Mutating a hashable object just isn't a nice thing to do ;-).  The objects also have no `__dict__` associated with them, so they'll probably be a little easier on your memory if you're creating 100M of them.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which hash function is that? I looked at hashlib but this one is a different one? Also I was thinking of this, but there is a high chance to get the same values for 2 different points with different coordinates when the number of points is say 100M, right? Maybe I should use something that's gonna be guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: The `hash` function that I used in the answer is the builtin function.  If it's good enough for python tuple, then it's good enough for me :).  There will probably be some hash collisions, but probably not too many and the underlying python machinery takes care of the collision resolution for you.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I asked is, I couldn't find the help for it. Google brings up hashlib when I type "python hash" :(

Comment: @JoanVenge -- Added a link which talks about `__hash__` and that has a link to the builtin `hash` (which really just calls `__hash__`).  What the exact algorithm is for tuples, I couldn't say (it's likely implementation dependent) -- But if it's good enough for the python core library, it's probably good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks mgilson that link was enough for me to read about the function.

Answer (score 0):

Hash codes aren't meant to be unique for unequal objects - there typically will be some collisions.  They definitely can't be used to test for equality.

Hash codes are used to place objects (hopefully) evenly across a data structure.  If you want to test for equality, test whether the coordinates are equal.

Comment: Thanks, I know what you mean, but the problem is the point groups are too large, so it will take too long to compare every point with every other. So that's I was thinking of somehow mapping the first set and then doing a lookup using the same mapping technique. I don't know if this is a common problem, not sure what it's called.

Comment: Most hashes are designed such that collisions only happen rarely, and not systematically. Cryptographic hashes in particular have the property that it is extremely difficult to find another set of data that will yield the same hash. With a properly sized hash, winning the lottery a thousand times in a row would be more likely than getting a single collision. This assumes that the hash is larger than the input data, of course. Otherwise you will have collisions quite often.

Comment: @John Venge You can still hash and add to a hash table, but you do then have to test the results for equality.  It will still greatly reduce the comparisons made.

Comment: Collision resolution is about the only nontrivial thing about hash tables. They've become very good at it. You don't even need a cryptographic hash function, or even one whose output appears evenly distributed. You just shouldn't have *terribly* many collisions.

Comment: Thanks guys. I imagine I will have too many collisions with a data made up of x, y, z of float values with 100M points, no?

Comment: The probability that one particular single hash will not collide with any other hash is (1-1/2^b)^(n-1), where b is the number of bits in the hash, and n is the number of items to hash. For there to be no collisions, this must be true for all the hashes, making the total probability (1-1/2^b)^(n(n-1)), I think. For relatively low n, this simplies to a collision probability of n(n-1)/2^b. So for a 64-bit hash, there would be a 1-in-a-million chance of a collision if there are about 4 million items to hash.

With 100M points, and 64 bit hash, the chance would be about 0.005%: quite significant.

Comment: C# Hashes are 32-bit, which gives you 4294967296 potential hashes.  Assuming that your hash function is well distributed, you will only have used a few percent of the available hash values.  It's highly likely you'll get collisions, but for any given point it's unlikely that there will be many collisions to test for.  Checking equality for each collision is still immeasurably better than testing every element.

Comment: Thanks guys. Hashtables would definitely be faster but is there a better way to deal with these problems? I remember someone telling me about mapping some data into a larger set for comparison or something but can't remember what exactly it was.

Comment: Have a look at [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-Tree)s and variants.  They are space partitioning trees, so identical points will end up in the same bucket.  They are also searchable by region, if that's useful.